# getPageContext().getRequest().getParameterMap() with multipart forms?

Tags: java, coldfusion, multipartform-data

below is the code i'm using to test this:

```
<cfif structkeyexists(form, "submitted")>
    <cfdump var="#getPageContext().getRequest().getParameterMap()#">
</cfif>

<cfoutput>
<form method="post" action="#cgi.script_name#?firstname=tony">
    <input type="text" size="50" name="page[contents][][content]">
    <input type="text" size="50" name="page[contents][][content]">
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
</cfoutput>
```

what we're doing is using getPageContext().getRequest().getParameterMap() to retrieve a hash of the form and url scopes during a post request. now this work all fine and dandy until you set the enctype attribute of the form to "multipart/form-data‎" like so:

```
<cfif structkeyexists(form, "submitted")>
    <cfdump var="#getPageContext().getRequest().getParameterMap()#">
</cfif>

<cfoutput>
<form method="post" action="#cgi.script_name#?firstname=tony" enctype="multipart/form-data‎">
    <input type="text" size="50" name="page[contents][][content]">
    <input type="text" size="50" name="page[contents][][content]">
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
</cfoutput>
```

what happens at this point is that none of the form field value are returned in the hash returned from getPageContext().getRequest().getParameterMap().

**does anyone know where or how we can get this data or a workaround?**

the whole reason we're using getPageContext().getRequest().getParameterMap() is because it returns an array as the value of the variable instead of a comma delimited list like using the form scope does.

**UPDATE:** this is on 8.0.1 with cumlative hotfix 4 applied.

**UPDATE:** The reason you can't use listToArray is because say you have two fields named *firstname* and the user enter in values for both fields (1 and 2). what CF will do is return a key in the form struct called *firstname* with a comma delimeted list for the two values (1,2). this is great, but say the **user enters in values for the field that contain commas** like 1,2,3,4 for the first field and 5,6,7,8 for the second field. the value in the form struct for *firstname* will be **1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8**. ***this isn't correct***. now since getParameterMap() returns an array for the value, **i would have two elements** like so: **["1,2,3,4","5,6,7,8"]**.

**UPDATE:** Tried seeing what getHttpRequestData().content would return per Leigh's suggest. It appears to be a blank binary.

**UPDATE:** Thanks you Leigh for figuring this out and without using getPageContext entirely. the trick was using getPartsArray() method on the form scope. I didn't even know this existed!

**Keep the ideas coming please!**

Comment: Which version of ColdFusion are you using? I'm not experiencing any difference in the results of your two snippets with CF8.

Comment: Could you just use listToArray to parse the content?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I do not think getParameter() is supposed to work with enctype="multipart/form-data". I believe you would need a different type of Request object ie One capable of parsing multipart requests.

Comment: Sorry. Meant to say getParmeter()/getParameterMap().

Comment: Are you sure Eric?  I'm using 8 and I get the same results as rip747.

Comment: @Leigh, during my research into this, yes, you are correct that getParameter() doesn't work with multipart. however i would like to find a work around for this. this problem is holding up a feature we're trying to implement into CFWheels. please any ideas would be welcomed.

Comment: @rip747 - My first thought would be to try parsing getHttpRequestData().content.  But I do not know if it is suitable for all cases. As I think it can return binary as well as a string.

Comment: @Leigh - getHttpRequestData().content doesn't return anything from an mulitpart post. content is a binary, but it's empty :P. Keep the ideas coming!

Comment: @Rip747 - Weird. I could have sworn it did with a test box and CF9/Tomcat.

Comment: Hmm.. it does for me.  I believe "content" is populated by calling the servlet's inputStream, which I _think_ should give access to the raw data.  Example: page%5Bcontents%5D%5B%5D%5Bcontent%5D=a&page%5Bcontents%5D%5B%5D%5Bcontent%5D=b&submitted=1

Comment: @Travis You're right. Turns out Firefox was changing the enctype on me - probably because I copy/pasted into a file from the Web and something carried over improperly. When I cleared it out and manually typed it in, I started getting rip747's results too.

Comment: @Rip747 - {Face plant} When I copied the sample from SO into eclipse I must have picked up a stray character. That hosed the encytype (multipart/form-dataâ€Ž) and made it fall back to the default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Okay.. take two) This seems to work with CF9. I am not able to test it with CF8 at the moment. Can you give it a whirl?

```
<cfif structkeyexists(form, "submitted")>
   <!--- if this is a multipart request ...--->
   <cfset variables.parts = form.getPartsArray()>
   <cfif structKeyExists(variables, "parts")>
      <cfoutput>   
      <cfloop array="#variables.parts#" index="p">
         <cfif p.isParam()>
            isParam() = #p.isParam()# <br />
            getName() = #p.getName()# <br />
            stringValue() = #p.getStringValue()# <hr />
         </cfif>
      </cfloop>
      </cfoutput>
   </cfif>
</cfif>
```

Comment: how in the world did you figure this out? please explain

Comment: It was an interesting problem, so I wrote up a quick blog entry on it. Feel free to skip to the end ;) http://cfsearching.blogspot.com/2010/02/form-field-values-multipart-forms-and.html

Comment: BTW: I forgot to say, glad it is solved .. and cool question :)

Comment: Can I just add my thanks Leigh, your solution to this problem just helped me out big time.